# idiomatic fallbacks in expression sfinae

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, function-prototypes

[Expression SFINAE](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2634.html) is a very handy way to write several alternative functions to do the same thing, and pick the best one which compiles. You mention the critical expression(s) in the function prototype, and if they're invalid, the prototype is ignored and another one will hopefully be picked.

This is very convenient, except for declaring the prototype for the case where the expression is undefined. Usually the set of prototypes must be divided into mutually exclusive domains, since they might be equal in the view of overload resolution and allowing two into the overload set would cause ambiguity.

One can always define an old-fashioned trait type for a given expression, for use with `std::enable_if`:

```
template< typename s, typename t, typename u, typename = void >
struct is_product_serializable : std::false_type {};

template< typename s, typename t, typename u >
struct is_product_serializable< s, t, u, typename std::conditional< true, void,
   decltype( std::declval< s >() << std::declval< t >() * std::declval< u >() )
>::type >
    : std::true_type {};
```

If it weren't for the need for something to derive from `false_type`, the `std::conditional` could go directly into the function prototype and all this boilerplate would go away.

Is there any kind of alternative? Perhaps some way to reduce the rank of a function overload that doesn't interfere with type deduction?

Comment: I haven't completely understood the question. Why can't you put those conditions on the function prototype? You say "if it weren't for the need to derive from `false_type`": why is that needed? That's only the case if you want to use tag dispatching, but you are not forced to. Why can't you use something like `typename enable_if<is_same<decltype(s << t * u), void>>::type` in the function prototype? Maybe I haven't understood what use case you have in mind.

Comment: @AndyProwl You named one condition. What about the opposite condition?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to add a dispatcher function which adds a dummy parameter, like a tag, for wiggle room to make the argument lists different.

```
// "Primary" template is just a dispatcher
template< typename ... args >
void chuck( args && ... rem ) {
    return chuck_impl( 0, std::forward< args >( a ) ... );
}

// preferred alternative matches int to 0 but is controlled by SFINAE
template< typename t, typename u, typename ... args >
auto chuck_impl( int, t && a, u && b, args && ... rem )
-> typename std::conditional< true, void, decltype( blah( a, rem ... ) * b ) >::type {
    blah( a, rem ... ) * b;
}

// fallback requires int => float conversion
template< typename t, typename u, typename ... args >
void chuck_impl( float, t && a, u && b, args && ... rem ) {
    bleh( a + chuck_impl( b, rem ... ) );
}
```

Comment: You might aswell clean up the SFINAE to `-> decltype((blah(a, rem...)*b), void())`.

Comment: @Xeo The only thing that seems to work reliably in GCC is `std::conditional`. I'm sick of trying alternatives. A cleaner version yet would be `decltype(void( blah(a, rem...)*b) ))`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for one version to work and for another not to, they both use the same mechanism, namely that if the expression inside `decltype` is ill-formed, you get a soft-error.

Comment: @Xeo That one mechanism doesn't necessarily treat all paths from A to B as equal. This issue is probably related to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55986